# need help to build and deploy ssis packages to Integration Services catalog

Tags: ssis, azure-devops, etl

I was following this interesting post regarding building SSIs project on Devops.

- [Continuous Integration for BI in VSTS: Splitting Build Steps by Project Type](http://www.msbiblog.com/2018/05/01/continuous-integration-for-bi-in-vsts-solution-folder-structure/#comment-4317)

Building worked fine, but I also need to deploy the ispac file to either local Integration Services catalog or on an Azure SQL DB integration catalog.

The ssisbuild tool can be used in a PowerShell task on Azure Devops and building works fine. But when I try using ssisdeploy I got problems.

here is my code (I use nuget tasks to download SSISBuild so it can be run on building and deploy. Below you see my code. Actually I don't need to find all ispac files since I just have one SSIS project. Hope any one can help me out here

Regards Geir

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.ispac -Recurse | Where-Object { -Not ($_.FullName -match "obj") } | ForEach-Object {
  &"$($env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY)\SSISBuild.2.3.0\tools\ssisdeploy" $_.FullName -Catalog SSISDB -Folder Test -ProjectName Testproject 

  if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
    throw "Build failed.";
  }
}
```

Comment: `But when I try using ssisdeploy I got problems.` What problems? Can you describe the problem? Did you get any error messages or codes?

Answer (score 1):

I usually follow these steps on SSMS to deploy and schedule my SSIS Package on server: 

1. Create a Catalog inside Integration Services-Catalog. 
2. Right click on this new Catalog and create a new folder inside it
[image]

3. After creating the folder you will have two sub-folders automatically created (Projects and Environment). 
[image]

Now Right click on the Project folder and add a project to it (from file system directory).

4. After this you can use SQL Server-Agent to add a new job and use the above added catalog 
   [image]

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

For deploying you need more values like Server, Username, Password etc.
take a look on https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSISBuild/#

```
A command line utility that deploys an SSIS deployment package to an SSIS catalog.
```

Syntax:

ssisdeploy [Ispac File] -ServerInstance <ServerInstanceName> -Catalog <CatalogName> -Folder <FolderName> -ProjectName <ProjectName> [-ProjectPassword <ProjectPassword>] [-EraseSensitiveInfo]

Switches:

Ispac File:
Full path to an SSIS deployment file (with ispac extension). If a deployment file is not specified, ssisdeploy searches current working directory for a file with ispac extension and uses that file.

-ServerInstance:
Required. Full Name of the target SQL Server instance.

-Catalog:
Name of the SSIS Catalog on the target server. If not supplied, then SSISDB value is used.

-Folder:
Required. Deployment folder within destination catalog.

-ProjectName:
Name of the project in the destination folder. If not supplied, then deployment file name is used.

-ProjectPassword:
Password to decrypt sensitive data for deployment.

-EraseSensitiveInfo:
Option to remove all sensitive info from the deployment ispac and deploy all sensitive parameters separately. If not specified then sensitive data will not be removed.

Example:

ssisdeploy.exe sample.ispac -ServerInstance dbserver\instance -Catalog SSISDB -Folder SampleFolder -ProjectName Sample -ProjectPassword xyz -EraseSensitiveI